# Create new object without primary keys angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some object like this

```
const objectValues = {
    "A": {
        "level": "1"
    },
    "B": {
        "active": "false"
    },
    "TEST": {
        "value": "abc",
        "must": "true"
    },
    "D": {
        "comma": "false",
        "show": "true",
        "use": "false"
    }};
```

I need to create new object that will look like this

```
const newObjectValues = {
        "level": "1"
        "active": "false"
        "value": "abc",
        "must": "true"
        "comma": "false",
        "show": "true",
        "use": "false"
    };
```

I need to remove keys in parent, like to remove **A, B, TEST** etc.The problem is that i need a function that will do that, because those values can be anything :(

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(objectValues).reduce((acc, val) => acc = {...acc,...obj[val]}, {})`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the spread syntax with `Object.assign()` and `Object.values()` as follows:

```js
const objectValues = {
    "A": {
        "level": "1"
    },
    "B": {
        "active": "false"
    },
    "TEST": {
        "value": "abc",
        "must": "true"
    },
    "D": {
        "comma": "false",
        "show": "true",
        "use": "false"
    }};
    
const result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(objectValues));

console.log(result);
```